cut metric and lp duality
I would like to show that the following two statements are equivalent.
Let (,)
be an 
-point metric space and 
a set of (C2)
pairs of points of 
.
Then ∃≥1
, an integer 
, and an embedding :→$^m$
s.t. ∀,∈
: (,)≤1((),())≤⋅(,)
where 1
denotes the 1
norm.
And the statement:
For every ,:→+
such that
∑(,)∈(,)(,)≤∑(,)∈(,)(,),
there exists a set ⊆
(not empty, not equal to 
), such that
∑(,)∈(,)(,)≤∑(,)∈(,)(,)
where 
is the cut metric of the set S.
I am given that for every 1≤t, the existence of f satisying the first statement can be written as an LP feasibility problem and I am to consider the dual of this LP.
Does anyone know how to do this?
